# Fitting a signal to a square wave form using lmfit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, lmfit

I want to fit data that follows a square wave pattern using the lmfit module. The trouble I am running into is that the while fitting the code does not vary from my starting guess of the frequency or the offset of the data. I read FAQ about this issue (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/faq.html) and it said this happens when the small changes in the variables does not affect the residual of the fit enough those variables are not changed at all.

Also, is there any good way to estimate the frequency of the signal to produce a good starting guess?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
from numpy import random

def square_wave(x, f, a, h, phi):
    return h + a * np.sign(np.cos( 2*np.pi*f*x + phi ))

def analyse(x,y):
    supermodel = Model(square_wave)

    print('Parameter names: {}'.format(supermodel.param_names))
    print('Indipendent variables: {}'.format(supermodel.independent_vars))

    params = supermodel.make_params(f = 5, a = (np.max(y)-np.min(y))/2 ,
                                    h = np.mean(y), phi = 0 )
    result = supermodel.fit(y, params, x=x)

    print(result.fit_report())

    plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
    plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--', label='initial fit')
    plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
                                    
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
f = 6

y = square_wave(t, f, a = 1, h = 0, phi = 0) + random.normal(0,0.1,t.size)

analyse(t,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

True step functions have a problem. They are not differentiable and if the jump is between data points a small change in frequency or phase probably does not change the chi-square value, such that the minimization algorithm stops incorrectly. A simple iterative approach solves this easily. Choose a  function that is differentiable and make it more square-like step-by-step.

Here is my approach:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def square_wave(x, f, a, h, phi):
    return h + a * np.sign(np.cos( 2 * np.pi *f * x + phi ) )

def soft_wave( x, f, a, h, phi, s=1 ):
    return h + a * np.tanh( s * np.cos( 2 * np.pi *f * x + phi ) )

def residuals( params, xdata, ydata, s ):
    f, a, h, phi = params
    yt = soft_wave( xdata, f, a, h, phi, s=s )
    return yt - ydata


tl = np.linspace( -2, 8.3, 67 )
sl = square_wave( tl, 0.39, 3.6, 2.1, 0.25 )
sl += normal( size=len(tl), scale=0.2 )
swl = soft_wave( tl, 0.39, 3.6, 2.1, 0.25, s=10 )

soldict = dict()
swdict=dict()
previous = ( 0.4, 4, 2, 0 )
for mys in range( 2, 26, 4 ):
    res = least_squares( residuals, x0=previous, args=( tl, sl, mys ) )
    print( res.x )
    previous = res.x
    soldict[mys] = np.append( res.x, mys )
    swdict[mys] = soft_wave( tl, *( soldict[mys] ) )

print (np.linalg.inv( np.dot( np.transpose( res.jac ), res.jac ) ) )

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(10,6))
ax= fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( tl, sl, ls='', marker='+' )
ax.plot( tl, swl )
for mys in range( 2, 26, 4 ):
    ax.plot( tl,swdict[mys] )
plt.show( )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a great help.